# How to do process auditing in Ubuntu without using Auditd or with default Ubuntu installation?

Tags: ubuntu

In a Linux system whenever an EXECVE syscall is called that time one process is created. In RHEL/CENTOS  the auditd service will log the details into the audit.log when you add a rule to log specific syscall. The Auditd service is installed by default in RHEL/CENTOS. But in Ubuntu case we dont have some inbuilt way to monitor that one. Is there a way to still do process auditing without installing extra tools ?

Comment: i think in rhel auditd is by default installed but not in ubuntu.